# Can a Corda network operator define additional certificate roles?

Tags: corda

By default, Corda networks have seven certificate roles:

1. Doorman
2. Network map
3. Service identity
4. Node certificate authority
5. Transport layer security (TLS)
6. Well-known legal identity
7. Confidential legal identity

The node certificate authority creates TLS certificates directly, but also issues certificates to the well-known legal identity, which is itself a CA (as it issues the confidential legal identity certificates).

We would like to add an eighth role. This role would be a certificate authority in charge of issuing the TLS certificates. Its certificate would be issued by the node certificate authority (who would no longer issue TLS certificates).

Is it possible to add an additional certificate role in this way? Or is the node hard-coded to only accept seven certificate roles?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add your own certificate role. The seven possible certificate roles are given by the [`CertRole` enum](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/d70cd26a7c73c75b7a18eb8f38795d1d94e066ed/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/internal/CertRole.kt#L26):

```
enum class CertRole(val validParents: NonEmptySet<CertRole?>, val isIdentity: Boolean, val isWellKnown: Boolean) : ASN1Encodable {
    /** Intermediate CA (Doorman service). */
    INTERMEDIATE_CA(NonEmptySet.of(null), false, false),
    /** Signing certificate for the network map. */
    NETWORK_MAP(NonEmptySet.of(null), false, false),
    /** Well known (publicly visible) identity of a service (such as notary). */
    SERVICE_IDENTITY(NonEmptySet.of(INTERMEDIATE_CA), true, true),
    /** Node level CA from which the TLS and well known identity certificates are issued. */
    NODE_CA(NonEmptySet.of(INTERMEDIATE_CA), false, false),
    /** Transport layer security certificate for a node. */
    TLS(NonEmptySet.of(NODE_CA), false, false),
    /** Well known (publicly visible) identity of a legal entity. */
    // TODO: at the moment, Legal Identity certs are issued by Node CA only. However, [INTERMEDIATE_CA] is also added
    //      as a valid parent of [LEGAL_IDENTITY] for backwards compatibility purposes (eg. if we decide TLS has its
    //      own Root CA and Intermediate CA directly issues Legal Identities; thus, there won't be a requirement for
    //      Node CA). Consider removing [INTERMEDIATE_CA] from [validParents] when the model is finalised.
    LEGAL_IDENTITY(NonEmptySet.of(INTERMEDIATE_CA, NODE_CA), true, true),
    /** Confidential (limited visibility) identity of a legal entity. */
    CONFIDENTIAL_LEGAL_IDENTITY(NonEmptySet.of(LEGAL_IDENTITY), true, false);
```

If you try to add a new certificate role, the node will fail as it will try to parse the certificate role as one of the enum values on start-up.